# Using c++ class method as a function callback

Tags: c++, function, methods, callback, std

I am using a camera API that calls a callback function every time there is a new image. The callback function is passed as:

```
BOOL WINAPI StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback(HANDLE hCamera, funcTransferEndCallback func, PVOID pvContext);
```

Where `funcTransferEndCallback` is:

```
typedef void (WINAPI *funcTransferEndCallback)(HANDLE hCamera, DWORD dwFrameNo, DWORD dwWidth, DWORD dwHeight, WORD wColorArray, PBYTE pbyteRaw, PVOID pvContext);
```

I don't want to make a callback function but actually use a method in a class instead. I am calling this `StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback()` inside my classe's constructor, so I can initialize the camera and pass my classe's method to capture every new frame and process it.

My method is defined in my class .h as:

```
public class Camera
{
public:
.....
void TakePicture(string pictureFileName);
void StartRecording(string videoFileName);
void StopRecording(void);
 .....
private:
volatile bool takePictureFlag;
volatile bool startRecordingFlag;
volatile bool stoptRecordingFlag;
void __stdcall TransferEndCallback(HANDLE hCamera, DWORD dwFrameNo, DWORD dwWidth, DWORD dwHeight, WORD wColorArray, PBYTE pbyteRaw, PVOID pvContext);
};
```

If I try this:

```
StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback(cameraHandle, TransferEndCallback, NULL);
```

Or this:

```
StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback(cameraHandle, this->TransferEndCallback, NULL)
```

Visual Studio 2013 says:

> error C3867: 'MyNamespace::MyClass::TransferEndCallback': function call missing argument list; use '&MyNamespace::MyClass::TransferEndCallback' to create a pointer to member

So I use it as suggested:

```
StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback(cameraHandle, &MyNamespace::MyClass::TransferEndCallback, NULL)
```

And I receive this error message:

> error C2664: 'BOOL StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback(HANDLE,funcTransferEndCallback,PVOID)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__stdcall MyNamespace::MyClass::* )(HANDLE,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,WORD,PBYTE,PVOID)' to 'funcTransferEndCallback' There is no context in which this conversion is possible

So, is it possible to pass a member method as a function? Is this a case for `std::bind`?

Comment: Make the function static.

Comment: I can't, I want to use some of the classe's member variables to control what the callback function is supposed to do when a frame arrives....using a static method will need global variables and than it's a mess that I want to avoid...also, if I am going to use global variables, I can just make it a global function and get rid of the problem...which isn't my goal since I do want the classes encapsulation.

Comment: If this is c++/cli ("public class Camera") things will get complicated!

Comment: First, static method does not mean global variables.  Pass your class instance via the pvContext argument.  Inside your callback, cast the void pointer back to a pointer to your class.

Comment: @DieterLücking This is native c++, but will be called by a c++/cli so a C# code can invoke it.....why does it get complicated?

Comment: @AnonMail but then I will need to make public all my private bool flags...it works, but I was looking for something more ideal. So is it impossible to convert between a method to a function?

Comment: If you can't use a static member function as the callback then you cannot do it.  Only a static member function has an address that can be used by the callback.  The class itself does not store function addresses, those go in objects and an object is transient.

Comment: Your private bool flags are not shown.  Get the thing to work first and then ask another question about encapsulating information.  Public/private is not the only way to protect access to data.

Comment: @P.Hinker but passing through a `this->` shouldn't give a method's address?

Comment: @AnonMail I wanted to make the question simpler...I will add some more stuff from the class then...

Comment: I wouldn't add anything to the question.  It's been answered.  Submit another question.

Comment: I am sorry Anon, but I disagree a bit with you...you guys gave me options on how to make it work, but my question is more on why doesn't it work....as far as I understand, a `this->` will bring the object's method address.

Comment: I've added an answer below.  Hopefully it will clear things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual pattern is to pass the instance pointer `this` into the `PVOID pvContext` parameter, then use it within the callback to call a member function.

```
public class Camera
{
// ...
void ThisTransferEndCallback(HANDLE hCamera, DWORD dwFrameNo, DWORD dwWidth, DWORD dwHeight, WORD wColorArray, PBYTE pbyteRaw);
static void __stdcall TransferEndCallback(HANDLE hCamera, DWORD dwFrameNo, DWORD dwWidth, DWORD dwHeight, WORD wColorArray, PBYTE pbyteRaw, PVOID pvContext);
};
```

Set the callback as

```
StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback(cameraHandle, TransferEndCallback, this);
```

Then write the static callback to dispatch it to the member function

```
void __stdcall Camera::TransferEndCallback(HANDLE hCamera, DWORD dwFrameNo, DWORD dwWidth, DWORD dwHeight, WORD wColorArray, PBYTE pbyteRaw, PVOID pvContext)
{
    ((Camera *)pvContext)->ThisTransferEndCallback(hCamera, dwFrameNo, dwWidth, dwHeight, wColorArray, pbyteRaw);
}
```

The above doesn't include error checking etc.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did, and I found out the reasons behind it in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/27/10492898.aspx TL;TD; it's because of the hidden this* passed for methods by the compiler.

Comment: @mFeinstein You are correct. The other point is that both your camera's library and the Win32 API (discussed in the linked article) expose plain C interfaces. This is primarily done for interop, since C is the lowest level which virtually all other higher-level languages know how to interface to. But C has no notion of objects, member functions or a `this` pointer. So that extra `void *pvContext` param is neither pretty nor type-safe, but it's the best a C interface can do to allow "context" information to be passed into the callback.

Answer (score 2):

The interface requires a `function` callback.  In `C++` that means a `non-member` function or `static` function.  That's because both of these types of functions are invoked without the need for an **instance of an class object**.  Member functions of a class are invoked differently and require an instance of a class object.

If you need more explanation, others can elaborate on how, under the hood, member functions are call.

Comment: i will accept your answer, but I would like to know indeed how does it work under the hood, because I can't see how's it different from `func()` to `this->func()`, since there will be a reference to an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
StTrg_SetTransferEndCallback(cameraHandle, &MyNamespace::MyClass::TransferEndCallback, NULL)
```

That will not work, because there is no object to call the method on.
As Anon Mail suggested, a static function is the best way to do that.
But, you stated that you can't do that.

My suggestion is to refactor your class into a singleton and add a static forward-function.
Example:

```
public class Camera
{
public:
static *Camera the()
{
  if (!singleton)
    singleton = new Camera;
  return singleton;
}
void destroy() { delete singleton; singleton = nullptr; }
 .....
private:
static void TransferEndCallbackForward(HANDLE hCamera, DWORD dwFrameNo, DWORD dwWidth, DWORD dwHeight, WORD wColorArray, PBYTE pbyteRaw, PVOID pvContext)
{
  assert(singleton != nullptr); // Implement your own error handling here
  singleton->TransferEndCallback(hCamera, dwFrameNo, dwWidth, dwHeight, wColorArray, pbyteRaw, pvContext);
}
void __stdcall TransferEndCallback(HANDLE hCamera, DWORD dwFrameNo, DWORD dwWidth, DWORD dwHeight, WORD wColorArray, PBYTE pbyteRaw, PVOID pvContext);
static Camera *singleton = nullptr;
};
```

I hope that can help you.

Comment: I tried to use `this->` so there will be a object reference...but it doesn't work either

Comment: You keep repeating this in spite of the fact that several have explained to you why it's a non sequitur.  this-> is an object reference but that doesn't change the fact that you cannot use that reference as the address for a callback.  If that object is destructed, what do you suppose will happen?  Since there's no guarantee that the object will remain through the life of the program, you cannot use that as the target of a callback.